# Removing all fragments causes error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an AsyncTask that fetches some stuff and based on the data received created some fragments. In case no data is returned, I do:

```
if (data.size() == 0) {
    List<Fragment> fragments = getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        FragmentTransaction txn = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) txn.remove(fragment);
        txn.commit();
    }
}
```

That piece of code causes "Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference". Any idea why?

I thought, that maybe during building the transaction, some old transaction is pending asynchronously, so I added

```
getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()
```

call before building the transaction. Still, the error is there.

Comment: where do you find method **getFragments()**?

Comment: sorry, meant child fragment manager, just edited the question

Comment: what method is this code part of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this error happening when you trying remove a null fragment reference from the transactions . So try this.

```
 if (data.size() == 0) {
            List<Fragment> fragments = getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
            if (fragments != null) {
                FragmentTransaction txn = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
                    if (fragment != null){
                        txn.remove(fragment);
                    }
                }
                txn.commit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: works. Just curious - why would getFragments() return a list with nulls?

Comment: I think for inactive fragment they will keep null reference.